# Vertical Acceleration of a Plane

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was given this homework question over the weekend and I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to proceed. It's basically calculating different factors of the descent of a plane. This particular section is vertical acceleration, which I know is the second derivative of the position function. Below is the equation I have for the position function where L is horizontal distance from "touchdown" at the origin.

I've arrived at the equation:

$$y = P(X) = \left(\frac{35000}{5280}\right)\left(-2*\frac{x^3}{L^3}+3*\frac{x^2}{L^2}\right)$$

$\left(\frac{35000}{5280}\right)$ is the cruising altitude of the plane converted from feet to miles.

What the question states is that "The pilot must maintain a constant horizontal speed `v` throughout the descent -- Interpret this as a derivative with respect to time t, so that the horizontal speed is $$\frac{dx}{dt}=v=300mi/hr$$
where
$$x(t)=L-300t$$
(from what I can tell, based on the fact that we are moving left across the graph to the origin and the derivative of `x(t)` is showing that $\frac{dx}{dt}=-300$)

It's telling me I need to use the chain rule to derive the following expression for vertical acceleration (This is the equation I'm supposed to arrive at):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}P(x(t))=90000\left(\frac{35000}{5280}\right)\left(\frac{6}{L^3}\right)\left(-L+600t\right)$$

So far I've tried substituting in $(L-300t)$ into the $P(x)$ formula and using a combination of quotient and chain rules with no success at all. If I derive the initial position formula then I don't see where chain rule is applicable. If anyone could atleast give me some tips on how to continue I would be grateful. If you need more information I'd be glad to provide it.

Thank you

Comment: My guess would be that your equation for $P(X)$ is incorrect. If I integrate the given $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ twice and substitute for $t$, I end up with something a bit different from what you’ve got. The cubic term is the same, but the coefficient of $x^2$ is different and there’s a term in $x$ that your $P(x)$ doesn’t have.

Comment: Upon reflection, the linear term I got can probably be eliminated by a suitable choice of constants of integration, but that still leaves a different coefficient for the quadratic term.

Comment: ... and for the cubic. I didn’t notice earlier that it had $L^3$ in the denominator instead of the $L^2$ you’ve got.

Comment: BTW, dimensional analysis is your friend when you run into problems like this. Your formula for $y$ should have the dimension of length, but, assuming that the two coefficients are dimensionless, it’s got $\text{length}^2 + \text{length}$ instead.

Comment: @amd apologies my P(x) had the wrong denominator for the first part it is $L^3$ under $x^3$, besides that it is correct my teacher gave us this formula to double check our answer. I also noticed I had written $(-L - 600t)$ instead of $(-L+600t)$ for the last part of the bottom equation. I must've been fading when I wrote this at 4am.

Comment: @amd Could you possibly show me your process in an answer so I could get an idea of what you did?

Comment: Looks OK with that change. Have you tried differentiating the new formula?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t need to use the quotient rule for this derivative. The chain rule is enough. To avoid clutter, I’ll let $A$ stand for the cruising altitude and $v_g$ the constant ground speed, so that $\dot x=v_g$ and $\ddot x=0$. For this formula, I found it a little easier to do the substitutions after differentiation:$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = A\left(\frac6{L^2}x-\frac6{L^3}x^2\right)\frac{dx}{dt}=v_gA\left(\frac6{L^2}x-\frac6{L^3}x^2\right) \\
\frac{d^2P}{dt^2}=v_gA\left(\frac6{L^2}-\frac{12}{L^3}x\right)\frac{dx}{dt}=v_g^2A\left(\frac6{L^3}\right)\left(L-2x\right)=v_g^2A\left(\frac6{L^3}\right)\left(-L-2v_gt\right)
$$ which, with $v_g=-300$ and $A=\frac{35000}{5280}$, matches the given solution.